# Multiple charsets: text/json; Charset=UTF-8;charset=utf-8 OkHttp Header

Tags: android, okhttp

Getting Multiple charsets: text/json; Charset=UTF-8;charset=utf-8 OkHttp Header while calling the server with okHttp Library. Someone know how can i fix this issue please .

```
public String post(String url, RequestBody body) {

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .addHeader("Content-Type","text/json;Charset=UTF-8")
        .post(body)
        .build();

        String str_response="";

        Response response;

        try {

            response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            try {

                str_response = response.body().string();
                System.out.println("POST_BODY_RESPONSE: "+" url "+url+" strresp "+str_response);

            } catch (Exception ex){

                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("POST_BODY_RESPONSE: ",url+" resp "+str_response);
            }

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            str_response = "";

        }catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            str_response = "";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

            str_response = "";
        }

        return str_response;
    }
```

04-30 15:27:12.118: W/System.err(7502): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple charsets: text/json; Charset=UTF-8;charset=utf-8
    04-30 15:27:12.118: W/System.err(7502):     at com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType.parse(MediaType.java:64)

```
    04-30 15:27:12.118: W/System.err(7502):     at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$RealResponseBody.contentType(Call.java:252)
    04-30 15:27:12.118: W/System.err(7502):     at com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody.charset(ResponseBody.java:86)
    04-30 15:27:12.118: W/System.err(7502):     at com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:82)
    04-30 15:27:12.128: W/System.err(7502):     at app.app.utils.OkHttp.post(OkHttp.java:75)
    04-30 15:27:12.128: W/System.err(7502):     at app.app.fragment.Login$2.run(Login.java:226)
    04-30 15:27:12.128: W/System.err(7502):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: I think it is not possible to pass different charsets at the same time. And what is the reason to pass `Charset=UTF-8` and `charset=utf-8` at the same time ? Here is the code of okhttp in gitHub, so you can see why you become the exception: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/MediaType.java

Comment: same issue arise when i remove addHeader(); should i remove the charset encoding on the server side also ?

Comment: I think that you should leave only the one charset (for example charset=utf-8) on the both sides

Comment: e.g.   .addHeader("Content-Type","Charset=UTF-8")

Comment: yes, I think it should be this way

Comment: i replaced charset with .header("User-Agent", "OkHttp Headers.java")
  .addHeader("Accept", "text/json; q=0.5")
  .addHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json") and it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your server to send the charset only once.